# What does "fu" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

> Bitch niggas always jackin' blood, but I know they fu

What does "fu" mean in this context? I'm sure it isn't "fuck you".

Comment: Where did you find this quote?

Comment: Dmitryi, this is not exactly standard English.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Psl6gFeoLWw
Lyrics say foo, which is probably short for fools/

Comment: @Avrumi yeah I thought he said fool/fools too, but on genius moderators changed it a few times, at first it was fool but now fu...

Comment: @J. Taylor, Shakespeare is not standart English too -_-

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDa5iGiPgGs
This song is by the same artist and in the intro they use the word fool but pronounce it foo

Comment: Also, it's presumptuous to assume 6ix9ine has a low IQ considering what he has set out to do. He wants money and fame, and through his music has accomplished his goals. That is more than most people can say. One can say his success is only because an entire generation is foolish, but I have many extremely intelligent friends that love his music and envy the lifestyle he touts. He has done incredibly foolish things but they don't necessarily correlate with his intelligence. This is only my opinion, and each are entitled to their own.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fu
This source actually says it means f*uck you, and its population base probably accurately represent the people who create and listen to this type of music.

Comment: @Avrumi I hope it's fool, then it's even more right with grammar point of view, I don't want to argue about 69, yeah he can do good shows and not only

Comment: Most anything goes in poetry and lyrics. It'd be nice to have a link to the full lyrics and original music too. How can you be sure it is not 'fuck you'?

Comment: I posted the video link above

Comment: @ Avrumi , Can I say 'they f*ck you'?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I am much more curious about "jacking blood".  According to UD,  *Jacking* is slang for ["stealing"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jackin) but why "blood"? Does the blood represent toil and sweat? Effort? Pain? Suffering?

As for “fu” I think it's the lowercase version of FU (F.U) an abbreviation of *fuck you*, the singer, 6ix9ine (*six nine*) is just pronouncing the initialism as if it were a word, he's turned it into an [acronym](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acronym). Yes, I did listen to the piece.

> **acronym**
>   An abbreviation formed from the initial letters of other words and pronounced as a word (e.g. ASCII, NASA).

Comment: He is saying about Bloods gang in that line, and jacking I think means to lie I have found it at UD. I saw a lot of lines where he sang he beat someone's ass but in fact he just had a beef spitting words ;)

Comment: @Дмитрий oh thanks, "blood gangs" makes a bit more sense now. Hmm... I checked the spelling and  it is written "**Bloods gang**" the "s" plural is tagged onto "blood". Fascinating!

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this context "fu" or "foo" means *skill, power or magic* - as in *kung-fu*, or *"my Google-foo is not working today"*.

> but I know they fu.

could be rephrased as:

> but I am onto them.

---

Sorry, no references for this one.

Comment: I seriously doubt that was the rapper's intention. The song is filled with expletives and outrage.